# Google Big Query exact WHERE

Tags: google-bigquery

sorry i have little experience with Google Big Query. I want to give a Query where the 'WHERE' Clause gives an exact output.

Right now my statements look like:

```
Select values
where values CONTAIN '8'
```

which gives me values containing

```
 8
 12,800
 12,8,20
 5,7,8
 100,8000
```

how can i alter the query to just give me

```
8
12,8,20
5,7,8
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want an exact match, but a partial match where the substring is 8 (optionally with commas around). You can try something like

Select values from your table
where 
REGEXP_MATCH(values, r'(^8$)|(^8,)|(,8,)|(,8$)')

which matches with a value of '8', or starting by '8,' or ',8,' in the middle or ending in ',8'